# CosmosDB Error 429 Unit Tests: Request Rate is Large

Tags: unit-testing, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, asp.net-core-webapi

I fixed the error of `Request rate is large` from CosmosDB by adding the `new ConnectionPolicy()` variable:

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUri), primaryKey, new ConnectionPolicy()
                    {
                        MaxConnectionLimit = 100,
                        ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
                        ConnectionProtocol = Protocol.Tcp,
                        RetryOptions = new RetryOptions() { MaxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests = 3, MaxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds = 60 }
                    });
```

But I was wondering how can we do unit test to make sure it is actually working?

**I am thinking of mocking the DocumentClient and set it up with heavy load. But I am not sure what the syntax should be like..**

Here are the sample unit test code for the happy case:

```
 var mockDocumentQuery = new Mock<IFakeDocumentQuery<BookModel>>();

            mockDocumentQuery
                .SetupSequence(_ => _.HasMoreResults)
                .Returns(true)
                .Returns(false);

            mockDocumentQuery
                .Setup(_ => _.ExecuteNextAsync<BookModel>(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>()))
                .ReturnsAsync(response);

            var provider = new Mock<IQueryProvider>();
            provider
                .Setup(_ => _.CreateQuery<BookModel>(It.IsAny<Expression>()))
                .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);

            mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<BookModel>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(provider.Object);
            mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<BookModel>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(dataSource.Expression);
            mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<BookModel>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dataSource.ElementType);
            mockDocumentQuery.As<IQueryable<BookModel>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => dataSource.GetEnumerator());

            var client = new Mock<IDocumentClient>();

            client.Setup(_ => _.CreateDocumentQuery<BookModel>(It.IsAny<Uri>(), It.IsAny<FeedOptions>()))
                  .Returns(mockDocumentQuery.Object);
```

In the last line of code, how can I setup the DocumentClient with a heavy load?

Comment: Aside from increasing RU on your collections under test, you can test against the emulator.

Comment: Surely unit tests should not be going over the wire. Instead you should mock the query calls.

Comment: @NickChapsas - "Surely?" Seems a bit strong, telling someone how they should test. Perhaps that approach works for you. Perhaps testing against the live database is required, for the OP.  And, as I've already suggested, use of the emulator (which is functionally equivalent to the actual Cosmos DB service) requires only a change to a connection string, vs the more significant effort of writing mocks.